# Cómo crear un archivo que contenga una variable tipo Arreglo de Objetos desde google sheet en Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo, javascript-objeto

Estoy aprendiendo en Google Apps Script. Estoy tratando de hacer un sistema que publique en una web productos tomando los datos de una *Google sheet*.
Para ello, tengo en una hoja de cálculo de Google Sheets los siguientes campos:

```
id, nombre, precio, url de la imagen.
```

La idea es completar la hoja de cálculo y se vayan publicando los productos en la web automáticamente.
Ahora, para ello necesito que se cree un archivo que actúe como base de datos, y se vaya actualizando.
Los datos de este archivo deben tener la siguiente forma:

```js
const baseDeDatos = [
    {
        id: 1,
        nombre: 'Patata',
        precio: 1,
        imagen: 'https://source.unsplash.com/random/500x500/?potato&sig=1'
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        nombre: 'Cebolla',
        precio: 1.2,
        imagen: 'https://source.unsplash.com/random/500x500/?onion&sig=2'
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        nombre: 'Calabacin',
        precio: 2.1,
        imagen: 'https://source.unsplash.com/random/500x500/?zucchini&sig=3'
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        nombre: 'Fresas',
        precio: 0.6,
        imagen: 'https://source.unsplash.com/random/500x500/?burrs&sig=4'
    },
    {
        id: 5,
        nombre: 'Zanahoria',
        precio: 4,
        imagen: 'https://source.unsplash.com/random/500x500/?potato&sig=1'
    }

];
```

La cuestión es que no estoy pudiendo crear ese archivo a partir de los datos de la hoja de cálculo.

Comment: Por favor muestra lo que has intentado. Preferentemente incluye un [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Array y sus métodos son muy prácticos para el manejo de los datos de hoja de cálculo.

El siguiente fragmento usa `Array.prototype.map()` y `Array.prototype.reduce()` (asumiendo que las hoja activa tiene cuatro columnas, una por cada propiedad en cierto orden:

```
const values = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getDataRange().getValues(); // obtener los valores
values.shift(); // remover los encabezados
const baseDeDatos = values.map(row => { // para cada fila...
    return ['id','nombre','precio','image'].reduce(  // nombre de las propiedades o "keys"
      (obj, key, col) => {
        obj[key] = row[col];
        return obj;
      }, 
      {});
});
```